# Java HttpClient get http reponse body missing carriage return (CRLF)

Tags: http, url, encoding, httpresponse

Use httpclient to get response body and found the CRLF is replaced by white space. 
if I check the request url with parameter manually(in browser), I can the the xml format response in expected format(with new line break). After I use ....BodyAsString().. then print... everything is in one line and the place supposed to be carriage return is replaced by white space.
Please help... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Content-Type header to UTF-8 when transmitting your data over HTTP. This should solve your problem.

Comment: The data I get from a web service(in this web service it calls db and get the data. I cannot access the web service code ), the only thing I can do is send the request and receive the http response. So that means I cannot set the content-Type. Right?

Comment: yea there is nothing to do in that case :). you can check with the WebService author if they handle this.

Comment: From the http response in browser I can see the new line break, but after I get the response by using Java httpClient, I cannot see it anymore.

Comment: dont you see them as CR LF characters? these are not displayable characters.Are you reading the response character by character from the outputstream? If not give that a try.

Comment: I get the http response(the xml format) and I checked it--view source(in IE browser) I can see the expected format with carriage return. I use httpclient and get the response body as string, then I print the response string, I found the place supposed to be carriage return(crlf) that is replaced by "white space". How could that be? why?

Comment: Java String encoder treat CRLF from http as white space?  
I am pulling my hair because of this issue....